# Resource bundle editing plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle

Is there a good resource bundle editing plugin for Eclipse?

The main feature I'm looking for is the possibility to see if the same keys exists in bundles for different languages.

I.e if I have two files `bundle_en_US.properties` and `bundle_sv_SE.properties` and they would have miss-matches in keys, eclipse would display an error.

I seem to remember that this was a default feature in Eclipse but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks promising:

[Eclipse Resource Bundle Editor](http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/)

> Eclipse plugin for editing Java resource bundles. Lets you manage all localized properties files in one screen. Some features: sorted keys, **warning icons on missing keys/values**, conversion to/from Unicode, hierarchical view of keys, more...

Comment: This one filled its purpose for me but it had some flaws and only worked in eclipse Juno, not Helios.

Comment: Good plugin. Unfortunately on Eclipse Luna current version (0.8.0) doesn't work: you extract files from downloaded archive to plugins or dropins folder but after restarting Eclipse the plugin is not active.

Comment: Eclipse Luna UPDATE:
You can restore plugin functionality installing on Eclipse the "Eclipse 2.0 style plugin support" from Eclipse Project Updates.
Or add an OSGi manifest to plugin files.
More details here: http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-rbe/discussion/442487/thread/cbf95f31/

Comment: This project has been migrated to GitHub: https://github.com/essiembre/eclipse-rbe

Now plugin version is 1.0.3 and it is working with 4.4

Comment: Would be nice to have this in a tabular overview with key/value as lines and language as column. This was avaiable in Sun's Java IDE 10 years ago or so. Having this view you can see at once what is missing. Pretty nice that was.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/tapiji/wiki/ExtendingCoreRBE and older [ResourceBundleEditor](http://dev.nightlabs.org/updatesites/development/) (which I used successfully in Helios, didn't try Juno yet).